# Is it possible for $this to return a __construct?

Tags: php, return-type, this

I am currently working on my PHP skills and at the moment I'm working with classes. What I want to do is to create a class for which I can echo the object. I have the following example:

```
    class good_stuff {
        public function __construct() {
            return "This is a function called by a construct from a class called: " .__CLASS__;
        }
        public function __toString() {
            return $this->self::__construct;
        }
    }

    $my_object = new good_stuff();
    echo $my_object;
```

I guess that my __toString is returning a wrong value, but I would like to know some details as $this doesn't seem properly documented. Is the only possible solution to this issue to define a property inside good_stuff and then assign and return it via __toString?

What I want to know is more information and a brief explanation of how $this works and what I'm missing from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: Returning a string at constructor of class does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `$this` (which is documented just fine).

The problem is that you trying to invoke a constructor manually (don't do that), and returning a value from a constructor (what sense does this make?) and forgetting the `()` that goes with a function call, while doing so.

I don't know why you're trying to find such a complicated solution. Simply return a string from your `toString()` function. Have it invoke another function in turn if you want to. But not the class constructor. That is not what it is for.

If the string to be returned by `toString()` is to be generated by the constructor, have the constructor store it as a [property](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Downvoter explain yourself.